# NVDI + PostGIS + ST_Mapalgebra

Tags: postgis, postgresql

I am following the PostGIS Cookbook's code to create an NDVI. I created the function but when using the example code but when I callback the function there seems to be an error... and I cannot figure out what is wrong.

This is the code I used:

```
SELECT ST_MapAlgebra(rast, ARRAY[1, 3, 4]::int[], -- only use the red, blue and near infrared bands
                     'raster.landsat8(double precision[], int[], text[])'::regprocedure,
                     -- signature for callback function '32BF',
                     -- output pixel type 'FIRST',
                     NULL, 0, 0, '1.', -- L '6.', -- C1 '7.5', -- C2 '2.5' -- G
                    ) AS rast
FROM raster.landsat8 m;
```

And this is what I got:

```
ERROR:  syntax error at or near ")"
LINE 6:      ) AS rast
             ^
SQL state: 42601
Character: 330
```

Comment: I'm not sure and I can't test, but it might be the trailing comma `,` in your parameters, i.e. change `NULL, 0, 0, '1.',` to `NULL, 0, 0, '1.'`

Comment: Yes, it most definately is the trailing comma. I also have no way to test it, but it is a syntax error at the given position.

Comment: That's it! Works flawlessly now. This might be a good post for other using PostGIS Cookbook by Zurbaran et al... the book has a typo! Many thanks :)

Comment: @FrankJimenez in this case I think it would be best for you to make a short answer to your own question and then accept that answer.